# How to get points that do not intersect, R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sf

I have two sets of points in coordinate system: A and B. All points in B are in A. So I want to pick the points in A which are not in B.
I'm using the sf library, but I'm little stuck.

Here I show a reproducible exameple. Consider the next data.

```
fname <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
nc <- st_read(fname)
library(sp)
library(sf)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
```

So I have the next two set of points A and B

```
A <- st_as_sf(meuse) %>% select(geometry) #155 obs
B <- filter(A, row_number()<= 100)%>% select(geometry) #100 obs
```

Starting from there, I want to rescue the points in A that are not in B, i.e., the remaining 55 points.

Comment: What are A and B? Are they polygons?

Comment: they are points

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly are your points stored?

Comment: So what do you mean "all points in B are in A"?. Do you mean that some of the points in A and B are identical, or do you mean that the points in B fall inside the convex hull of the points in A? It's much easier to help you with a reproducible example so that there is less ambiguity in what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can use the `%in%` operator or the `st_difference` function.  If using `st_difference`, you might need to `st_combine` each set individually if the points are `sf` but not if they're `sfc`.

The methods may differ a little depending on the type of data you're using.  Are they just points(sfc), or are they points associated with data(sf)?

*Edit for your reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(sf)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y

A <- st_as_sf(meuse) %>% select(geometry) #155 obs
B <- filter(A, row_number()<= 100)%>% select(geometry) #100 obs

diff_meuse <- st_difference(st_combine(A), st_combine(B)) %>% st_cast('POINT')

diff_meuse
#> Geometry set for 55 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 178786 ymin: 329714 xmax: 180923 ymax: 333116
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 5 geometries:
#> POINT (178786 329822)
#> POINT (178875 330311)
#> POINT (179024 329733)
#> POINT (179030 330082)
#> POINT (179034 330561)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = A, size = 4, alpha = .3) + 
  geom_sf(data = diff_meuse, color = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

````
``` r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)

# using nc data incl w/sf
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source  
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27

a_b <- st_sample(nc, size = 20)

a <- a_b[1:20] 
b <- a_b[1:5]  

diff <- a[!a%in%b]
head(diff)
#> Geometry set for 6 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.98142 ymin: 34.15653 xmax: -78.5457 ymax: 36.41477
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 5 geometries:
#> POINT (-78.5457 34.15653)
#> POINT (-79.28979 36.045)
#> POINT (-79.03986 36.41477)
#> POINT (-80.52165 35.15185)
#> POINT (-81.98142 35.45012)

## or using st_difference
diff_st <- st_difference(st_combine(a), st_combine(b))
head(st_cast(diff_st, 'POINT'))
#> Geometry set for 6 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -82.19945 ymin: 35.11489 xmax: -80.52165 ymax: 35.93451
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 5 geometries:
#> POINT (-82.19945 35.93451)
#> POINT (-80.57638 35.60809)
#> POINT (-80.72523 35.14048)
#> POINT (-80.78783 35.11489)
#> POINT (-80.52165 35.15185)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = diff, color = "black", alpha = .2, size = 6) +
  geom_sf(data = diff_st, color = "black", alpha = .8, size = 4) + 
  geom_sf(data = a, color = 'red', size = 1)
````

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!! It worked for me using st_difference. When I tried using %in% operator in my reproducible example it didn't work.

Comment: @ConstanzaZepeda You're welcome, I've updated the answer with the code & data you provided in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using `st_difference` is perfectly fine, but, in some cases using spatial operations can be costly (in time and memory).

So for this example you could consider treating the data as `data.frame`s, rather than spatial objects, and use an 'anti-join'

```r
library(data.table)
library(sfheaders)

## Convert to data.frame/data.table
dfA <- sfheaders::sf_to_df(A, fill = T)
dfB <- sfheaders::sf_to_df(B, fill = T)

setDT(dfA)
setDT(dfB)

## do an 'anti-join' to find those in A but not in B 
dfA[ !dfB, on = .(x, y) ]

## I prefer using data.table, but the same anti-join exists in dplyr
dplyr::anti_join(dfA, dfB, by = c("x","y"))


library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = A, size = 4, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = dfA[ !dfB, on = .(x, y) ], aes(x = x, y = y), colour = 'red')
```

[image]